# How to retrieve the "Authorization token" from a portal (employer portal with SSO)?

Tags: python, automation, authorization, single-sign-on, token

When I open the portal in a browser, it automatically logs me in through SSO. 
Once logged-in, I want to retrieve the Authorization token, which I can use to automate few other purposes, like - apply leaves for a particular date, fill timesheets, etc. using a python code.

I am currently able to perform these actions by **manually** copying the token from the *chrome* inspect window and hardcoding the same in my python code (using requests module in python). However, in order to truly **automate** the process, I need to dynamically retrieve the authorization token, which refreshes everyday.

Here is the snippet of the code I am using.

```
url = 'mycompanyportal url for leaves module'

headers={"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Accept" : "application/json",
"Cookie": "_ga=GA1.2.18131865....................................",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36",
"Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1...................................."
}

       for leaveDate in leaveDates:
            r = requests.post(url, allow_redirects=True, data={
            'comments': "COVID-19 BCP",
            'fromDate': leaveDate,
            'isHalfDay': "N",
            'leaveType': "WFH",
            'leaveTypeId': 3,
            'toDate': leaveDate
            }, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You need to look for the process, using which the website is obtaining the Authorization code and then you have to imitate the same in the code.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this? I observed a bunch of get and option type requests till the authorization token is generated. Perhaps I can mimic these steps as well with python, question remains how do I retrieve the token itself when it is generated?

Comment: Just try to figure out how the website is getting the token. We just need to follow the same.